# webiste picture not dysplayed full size on phone

Tags: html, css

I'm novice in html and css and I have an issue with my site whendysplaying the images on phone and pc.
On phone I cannot see the full size of the picture, I guess is because of the resolution on phone is smaller. There is any possibility to show the images on the same way on phone and pc?
Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope it helps you.

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: url(../images/__emre__.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center, center;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, in fact I add a #showPicture id with the css that you provide me but still the same

Comment: Actually correct solution is to use media query depends on the screens.